SwiftUI border not wrapping whole view when one item is scaled
Before asking the question, I want to say I am still quite new at SwiftUI so apologies if I don't make sense.
From the following code:
struct ScaledBorderedView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { index in
                let isSelected = index == 0
                let scale: CGFloat = isSelected ? 3 : 1
                let size = CGSize(
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10
                )

                Circle()
                    .border(.red)
                    .frame(
                        width: size.width,
                        height: size.height
                    )
                    .scaleEffect(scale)

            }
        }
        .border(.green)
    }
}


I am trying to figure out why the HStack is not proposing that the height is 30 to the green border.

Scaling does not change the ideal dimensions of a view (nor does an offset, or a rotation effect, btw).

It's a scale "effect".  It doesn't affect the frame. It just affects its look.

The effect of scaleEffect is only visual. It does not affect the "logical frame" of the circle. See also the "Discussion" section of the documentation, where a similar border is shown. The same also applies for many other view modifiers that has a counterpart in VisualEffect, e.g. offset, rotationEffect and so on.
You can account for this by adding some .padding(10) before .border(.green). You can also change the frame of the circle, but this would affect layout.
